# riot-im:Your Riot is misconfigured Invalid homeserver discovery response

Tags: chat

I install riot-desktop version on my debian.

```
sudo wget -O /usr/share/keyrings/riot-im-archive-keyring.gpg https://packages.riot.im/debian/riot-im-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/riot-im-archive-keyring.gpg] https://packages.riot.im/debian/ default main" |
    sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/riot-im.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install riot-desktop
```

Now start it with menu `internet-riot`,

[image]

How to config my riot ,googled ,no good material to read.